# In what namespace is the disk UUID unique?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, restore

I have restored a backup that had an attached data disk to a new VM.  When I issue the command `sudo blkid` I see that it has the same UUID as the data disk that is attached to the original VM, so I don't have to change the fstab to mount it on boot.  However, it seems to be a physically different disk, i.e I can see files updating on the disk attached to the original VM but not the restored one.  I thought the UUID would be globally unique but apparently not.   So what namespace is it unique in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UUID of a disk is always unique for a newly created VM. But when we do the below mentioned operations then the UUID doesn't remain unique :

1. When we make a copy of the VHD's of a VM.
2. When we use a VM image to deploy a new VM.
3. When we take a capture of the image with attached data disks , OS
   disk UUID will be the same and we must make the copy of the attached
   disks whose UUID will also be the same.

Your case which is the 3rd option and for it you have to create a copy of data disk as mentioned by [Alexandre Brisebois in his blog](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2015/09/01/disk-uuids-and-linux-on-azure/):

> a copy of the Data Disks is required to keep the Data Disk UUIDs.
> Without these disks, a Virtual Machine created from the VM Image would
> result in a prompt a boot time. This prompt appears because the
> Virtual Machine is unable to find the Partition UUIDs that match the
> UUIDs from the fstab. Ultimately, this can result in a failed
> deployment and create can be challenging to troubleshoot and fix.

In your case, its expected that the files are getting stored in the data disk of the original VM and not the restored one. As a solution , you can take the image of the OS disk only by detaching the Data disk from the VM and after deploying the new VM from the image then you can attach the data disk.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  In fact, the observed behavior is what I want - I wanted to completely independent machines.

Comment: hello @farhadf, gald to be of help !! couldn't get you here " In fact, the observed behavior is what I want - I wanted to completely independent machines." . If you want the observed behavior then you don't need to do any changes, you need a copy the data disks as well so that when the copy is attached to the other VM the files are stored there as it has the same UUID .. but if you want independent machines then create a Image by dettaching the data disk and create the VM from the Os disk image only ..